# Como baixar mais de um arquivo Chromedriver sem pedir autorização de download

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando baixar mais de uma arquivo pelo chrome e fica aparecendo a mensagem de permissão [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

teria alguma forma de aceitar automaticamente

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
```

Encontrei a solução, para quem precisar!